# How to replace all id from href?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following markup

```
<div class = "general">
  <a href = "#world"></a>
  <div id ="custom"></div>
</div>
```

How to change `id = "custom"` in all `<div>` with `class="general"` from `href` on page using jQuery?

Comment: Read [how to ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask),  have you actually did any research? googling "jquery accessing child elements" and "jquery edit attribute" gives you the answer quite fast.

Comment: @AlexanderKolovsky Did my answer help? If so, please accept. If not, please give feedback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through all div.general and replace the id attribute of div#custom to whatever is there as the anchors href property. The following code will work:

```
$(".general").each(function(){
    $(this).find("#custom").attr("id", $(this).find("a").attr("href").replace("#", ""));
})
```

Here the .find() will dig out elements from any depth inside the parent. If you are sure about the DOM position of the elements, you can change the .find() to .children()

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
$("div.general").each(function() {
    $(this).children("div#custom").text($(this).children("a").attr("href"));
});
```

If I understand you correctly, you want to iterate through all `div.general`s, and change the text of each child `div#custom` to the `href` of the child `a`.

See a working example on [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jlam55555/yqomxvps/).

---

Also, another tip is to avoid using multiple elements with the same `id`. In your code you have a `<div>` with `id="custom"`. You also say that the `div.general` appears multiple times — therefore, the `id` "custom" will appear multiple times. [This is bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611963/can-multiple-different-html-elements-have-the-same-id-if-theyre-different-types). I suggest that you change `id` to `class`.